# Breadcrumbs with different paths in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, breadcrumbs

Path 1:

```
<div class="breadcrumb-inner">
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 73px;">
  <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul class="breadcrumb">

                    <li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="whitepaper.html"><span>Papers</span></a></li>
                    <li class="active"><span>Download Paper</span></li>

                </ul>
         </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Path 2:

```
<div class="breadcrumb-inner">
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 73px;">
  <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul class="breadcrumb">

                    <li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="whitepaper.html"><span>Industries</span></a></li>
                    <li class="active"><span>Download Paper</span></li>

                </ul>
         </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Above is my bootstrap breadcrumb code.so here i want to attain the hierarchy(ie; want to go to the single page from  two paths)

1. Home -> paper-> download paper
2. Home -> industries -> download paper

So how can i change my code to attain two or more paths to get to my destination page.any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't get it, are you asking how to change `whitepaper.html` into something else ?

Comment: @adeneo  downloadpaper.html is a html page and i want to show a breadcrumb for that page but the page has to check the path whether it is coming from paper.html(home->paper.html->downloadpaper.html) or industries.html(home->industries.html->downloadpaper.html) and show the breadcrumb accordingly.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle demo ?

Comment: You could add a ```data-parent=""``` attribute to anchor,  you can know who is the parent. or maybe a ```data-family```